# save facebook login data after login - Kotlin

Tags: java, android, facebook, kotlin, authentication

i have a normal registration that ask the user for username,email,gender, and password,
and these info are stored in Firebase

so the normal registration is working fine and the data is saved in Firebase after registration

here is the onclick for registration button:

```
if ( !validateName() || !validateUsername() || !validatePassword()) {
            return@setOnClickListener
        } else {

            progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            val name = mUsername.editableText.toString().trim()
            val email = mEmail.editableText.toString().trim()
            val password = mPassword.editableText.toString().trim()
            val gender = mGender.editableText.toString().trim()

            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(object : OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> {
                    override fun onComplete(p0: Task<AuthResult>) {
                        Log.e("zzzzz",p0.isSuccessful.toString())
                        if (p0.isSuccessful) {

                            FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().getToken(true).addOnCompleteListener {
                                var fbToken = it.result!!.token


                                val sharedPreference2 = getSharedPreferences("isLogin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                                var editor2 = sharedPreference2.edit()
                                editor2.putBoolean("isLogin", true)
                                editor2.putString("UserToken", fbToken)
                                editor2.commit()


                                Log.e("ggg",fbToken)
                                // DO your thing with your firebase token
                            }

                            val signupdata = Signupdata(name, email, password, gender)





                            var okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
                                addInterceptor(
                                    Interceptor { chain ->
                                        val builder = chain.request().newBuilder()
                                        builder.header("X-App-Version", "0")
                                        builder.header("X-Platform", "0")
                                        builder.header("X-Auth-Token", "0")
                                        return@Interceptor chain.proceed(builder.build())
                                    }
                                )
                            }.build()

                            val apiInterface2 = ApiInterface2.create().getMovies()

                            //apiInterface.enqueue( Callback<List<Movie>>())
                            apiInterface2.enqueue(object : Callback<MutableList<Duadata>> {
                                override fun onResponse(
                                    call: Call<MutableList<Duadata>>?,
                                    response: Response<MutableList<Duadata>>?
                                ) {

                                    //   Log.e("res", response!!.body().toString())

                                    if (response?.body() != null)
                                        response.body()!!
                                }

                                override fun onFailure(call: Call<MutableList<Duadata>>?, t: Throwable?) {

                                }
                            })


                            val sharedPreference3 = getSharedPreferences("isLogin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                            var editor3 = sharedPreference3.edit()
                            //  editor2.putString("UserToken", it.token.toString())





                            val sharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("User_Data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                            var editor = sharedPreference.edit()
                            editor.putString("user_id", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
                            editor.putString("email_id", email)
                            editor.putString("username",name)
                            editor.putString("gender",gender)
                            editor.commit()





                            Toast.makeText(
                                applicationContext,
                                "Registered Successfully!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()




                            val intent =
                                Intent(this@SignupActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                            intent.putExtra("user_id",
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
                            )
                            intent.putExtra("email_id", email)
                            startActivity(intent)
                            finish()


                        } else {


                            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                            Toast.makeText(
                                applicationContext,
                                p0.exception?.message,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show()
                            Log.e("TAG_P", "failure!", p0.exception)
                        }
                    }

                })
        }
```

the above code is working fine.

now i'm trying to make a facebook login as below:

```
@SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
fun getUserProfile(token: AccessToken?, userId: String?) {

    val parameters = Bundle()
    parameters.putString(
        "fields",
        "id, first_name, middle_name, last_name, name, picture, email"
    )
    GraphRequest(token,
        "/$userId/",
        parameters,
        HttpMethod.GET,
        GraphRequest.Callback { response ->
            val jsonObject = response.jsonObject

            // Facebook Access Token
            // You can see Access Token only in Debug mode.
            // You can't see it in Logcat using Log.d, Facebook did that to avoid leaking user's access token.
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                FacebookSdk.setIsDebugEnabled(true)
                FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS)
            }
            accessToken = token.toString()

            // Facebook Id
            if (jsonObject.has("id")) {
                val facebookId = jsonObject.getString("id")
                Log.i("Facebook Id: ", facebookId.toString())
                id = facebookId.toString()
            } else {
                Log.i("Facebook Id: ", "Not exists")
                id = "Not exists"
            }


            // Facebook First Name
            if (jsonObject.has("first_name")) {
                val facebookFirstName = jsonObject.getString("first_name")
                Log.i("Facebook First Name: ", facebookFirstName)
                firstName = facebookFirstName
            } else {
                Log.i("Facebook First Name: ", "Not exists")
                firstName = "Not exists"
            }


            // Facebook Middle Name
            if (jsonObject.has("middle_name")) {
                val facebookMiddleName = jsonObject.getString("middle_name")
                Log.i("Facebook Middle Name: ", facebookMiddleName)
                middleName = facebookMiddleName
            } else {
                Log.i("Facebook Middle Name: ", "Not exists")
                middleName = "Not exists"
            }


            // Facebook Last Name
            if (jsonObject.has("last_name")) {
                val facebookLastName = jsonObject.getString("last_name")
                Log.i("Facebook Last Name: ", facebookLastName)
                lastName = facebookLastName
            } else {
                Log.i("Facebook Last Name: ", "Not exists")
                lastName = "Not exists"
            }


            // Facebook Name
            if (jsonObject.has("name")) {
                val facebookName = jsonObject.getString("name")
                Log.i("Facebook Name: ", facebookName)
                name = facebookName
            } else {
                Log.i("Facebook Name: ", "Not exists")
                name = "Not exists"
            }


            // Facebook Profile Pic URL
            if (jsonObject.has("picture")) {
                val facebookPictureObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("picture")
                if (facebookPictureObject.has("data")) {
                    val facebookDataObject = facebookPictureObject.getJSONObject("data")
                    if (facebookDataObject.has("url")) {
                        val facebookProfilePicURL = facebookDataObject.getString("url")
                        Log.i("Facebook Profile Pic URL: ", facebookProfilePicURL)
                        picture = facebookProfilePicURL
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.i("Facebook Profile Pic URL: ", "Not exists")
                picture = "Not exists"
            }

            // Facebook Email
            if (jsonObject.has("email")) {
                val facebookEmail = jsonObject.getString("email")
                Log.i("Facebook Email: ", facebookEmail)
                email = facebookEmail
            } else {
                Log.i("Facebook Email: ", "Not exists")
                email = "Not exists"
            }

            openDetailsActivity()
        }).executeAsync()
}

private fun openDetailsActivity() {
    FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().getToken(true).addOnCompleteListener {
        

        
    }
    val myIntent = Intent(this, DetailsActivity::class.java)
    myIntent.putExtra("facebook_id", id)
    myIntent.putExtra("facebook_first_name", firstName)
    myIntent.putExtra("facebook_middle_name", middleName)
    myIntent.putExtra("facebook_last_name", lastName)
    myIntent.putExtra("facebook_name", name)
    myIntent.putExtra("facebook_picture", picture)
    myIntent.putExtra("facebook_email", email)
    myIntent.putExtra("facebook_access_token", accessToken)
    startActivity(myIntent)
}
```

the login is completed this way and i get navigate to "DetailsActivity" and i can see the info from Facebook login

here is what I'm trying to do now

I'm trying to save these data from Facebook the same way its saved if the user used normal registration, i tried to use the sharedPreference and same way from normal registration page in many ways but i couldn't do it

"I'm still learning Kotlin (beginner) so please be patient with me and if you know how to solve this problem, please go with me step by step"

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is going wrong when you're trying to save it in `SharedPreferences` ? Can you share that code ?

Comment: in the first code there is "val sharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("User_Data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                            var editor = sharedPreference.edit()
                            editor.putString("user_id", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
                            editor.putString("email_id", email)
                            editor.putString("username",name)
                            editor.putString("gender",gender)
                            editor.commit()"
i want to use this as well to save facebook data login, i can't achieve this

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're using `editor.commit()`

```
val sharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("User_Data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
var editor = sharedPreference.edit()
editor.putString("user_id", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
editor.putString("email_id", email)
editor.putString("username",name)
editor.putString("gender",gender)
editor.commit()
```

According to the docs, it is recommended to use `editor.apply()` since it writes the updates to disk asynchronously. [read more](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#WriteSharedPreference)

---

Here's a code snippet I use in my project.

```
private val preference: SharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(requireContext())
preference.edit()
    .putString("KEY", "VALUE")
    .putString("KEY", "VALUE")
    .apply()
```

Comment: "User_Data" table is working fine, i meant that i want to use the same table to save facebook data(second code in my question)